# ¿Como cambiar idioma de datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo el siguiente código para la selección de un rango de fechas.

Necesito cambiarlo a español, vi varios ejemplos pero no funcionó.
No se donde agregar ni como el código para cambiar el idioma.

```
<div class="row" title="Filtro Fecha" style="margin-top: 5px"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 5px;">
        <div class="input-group input-daterange">
            <h:inputText id="startDate1" name="startDate1" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value=""/>                          
            <h:inputText  id="endDate1" name="endDate1" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value=""/>                             
        </div>
    </div>                   
</div>
```

y el `script` para el rango de fechas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true
        });                     
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner el `datepicker` de `jQuery` en español:

```
<script>
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
 closeText: 'Cerrar',
 prevText: '< Ant',
 nextText: 'Sig >',
 currentText: 'Hoy',
 monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
 monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
 dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
 dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
 weekHeader: 'Sm',
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 firstDay: 1,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: ''
 };
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
$(function () {
$("#fecha").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Lo tengo hecho en varios proyectos míos y funciona perfecto. Espero que pueda servirte!

Comment: Hola Mario, ¿currentText: 'Hoy', no se usa "Today"en lugar de "currentText"?

Comment: hola Mario! Donde agrego ese script?

Comment: @Jorgesys he buscado en otros ejemplos por la red y creo que es correcto como lo he puesto.

Comment: @VaneUstra Prueba a ponerlo dentro de tu script de rango de fechas.

Comment: @MarioGuiber me parece que no hay script de rango de fechas en este caso, es un DatePicker.

Comment: @Jorgesys Tienes razón.. No tiene sentido ese rango de fechas. Gracias por el aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de [`JQuery UI DatePicker`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) para localizar el `widget` (*"**Localization**"*) se puede descagar e incluir alguno de [los archivos `JS` ubicados aquí](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n)

***OBS**: Si se desea usar un CDN, una opcion es [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui/1.10.1)*

---

Por defecto, al cargarse cada uno de estos archivo se establecen como el idioma por defecto

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(e.datepicker.regional[LANG]);
```

Se puede restaurar la localizacion predeterminada con:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[""]);
```

Adicionalmente se puede establecer una localización para un selector específico:

```
$(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(() => {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando React con Material ui puedes usar esto.(If you are using React with Material ui you can use this)

```
 import { DesktopDatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
 import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'
 import esLocale from 'date-fns/locale/es'

  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale={esLocale}>
          <DesktopDatePicker
            label="Fecha de nacimiento"
            value={personalInformation.birthDate}
            inputFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            onChange={(newValue) => {
              if (newValue === null) {
                return
              }
              handleChangePersonalInformation('birthDate', newValue)
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                fullWidth
                required
                variant="standard"
                sx={{
                  minWidth: '230px',
                  maxWidth: '230px',
                }}
                error={haveError('birthDate')}
                helperText={errorMessages('birthDate')}
              />
            )}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
```